# How can I list references from BibTeX file in-line with commentary?

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to take the full citation of a reference in my BibTeX file and write commentary in-line after it.  A `\fullcitation{id}` command would be perfect.  I would like to use it as:

```
\fullcitation{id1}
```

This paper talks about A with applications to B.

```
\fullcitation{id2}
```

This paper considers how C affects A.

Whenever the `\fullcitation{id}` command appears, I want it to be replaced with the full reference, including authors, title, journal, and date.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want full citations in the main text, then you can use the `bibentry` package. Distributed as part of [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib). Use it as:

```
\nobibliography{bibfile1,bibfile2} % or starred if also using \bibliography{...} 
See \bibentry{id1} for a pedagogical introduction or \bibentry{id2} for more
technical details.
```

See also [this FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-bibinline).

Or perhaps you just want to add annotations to a regular list-style bibliography (i.e., a section of it's own). For this purpose, some bibliography styles will honour an `annote` field, and otherwise you can usually abuse the `note` field to achieve something similar.

Comment: Could you please write a MWE?  I'm not getting how to use it (specially because I'm using `\bibliography{mybibfile}` and I'm not sure where the `\nobiblipgrahy` should go.

Answer (score 44):

Here's how to do it using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This paper is really cool:

\fullcite{Bli74}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the filecontents package here?

Comment: You're right. My code example was manufactured from a more general file `biblatextest.tex` which I use to test biblatex features on the fly - and for this purpose, the filecontents package feature that allows overwriting an existing (bib) file comes in handy.

Comment: An alternative biblatex solution would just be to use `\usepackage[citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}`

Comment: When I use fullcite it only prints first-collaborator and collaborators. How can I get the full name of all of them? The main bibliography is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use \nobibliography, \usepackage{bibentry} and \bibentry{foo}. Here you are an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Look ma, inline bibtex entries:

\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{michael}
\item \bibentry{elvis}
\end{itemize}

\section{And now for something completely different}
Lorem ipsum yada yada,
also see \cite{britney}, 
yada yada, and \cite{marilyn} too.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{test_bibentry.bib}

\end{document}
```

For the details see this webpage:
https://www.stefaanlippens.net/bibentry/

Additionally, if you don't want the section References to be shown, you could substitute \bibliography{test_bibentry.bib} by \nobibliography{test_bibentry.bib}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok, I have edited it