# Display Reference in document

Tags: bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I list references from BibTeX file in-line with commentary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2905/how-can-i-list-references-from-bibtex-file-in-line-with-commentary)

Is it possible to display reference information inline with the reference? I use `\cite{reference}` to cite work but is there a command that would display the reference in my text. I have:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{linkToBibTex}
```

But I need to show the details of a reference in my text is it possible? And I don't just want to show a reference number.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: [How can I list references from BibTeX file in-line with commentary?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2905/how-can-i-list-references-from-bibtex-file-in-line-with-commentary)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) and the [`bibentry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibentry) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % only needed to include sample bib file
% This is the sample bib file
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib} 
@article{glashow,
    Journal = {Nucl.~Phys.},
    Author = {Glashow, Sheldon},
    Pages = {579--588},
    Title = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
    Volume = {22},
    Year = {1961}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib,bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
\nobibliography{test.bib}
This is a complete citation: \bibentry{glashow}

\end{document}
```

You can also do it easily with [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % only needed to include a sample bib file
% This is the sample bib file
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib} 
@article{glashow,
    Author = {Glashow, Sheldon},
    Journal = {Nucl.~Phys.},
    Pages = {579--588},
    Title = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
    Volume = {22},
    Year = 1961}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test.bib}
\begin{document}
This is a complete citation: \fullcite{glashow}

\end{document}
```

If you are just beginning with bibliographies I would go with the `biblatex` solution, since it provides a much easier interface for modifying the formatting. (Although there are many existing `.bst` files available for `natbib`.)