# Multiple bibliographies (reference lists) using embedded bibliography database

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, multibib, subdividing

I would like to have multiple bibliographies (reference lists) as described in  [Airminded · Multiple bibliographies in LaTeX](http://airminded.org/2006/02/25/multiple-bibliographies-in-latex/) ([TeX Frequently Asked Questions -- question label "multbib"](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multbib)).

However, I'd like to use with a single .tex file, which would contain the bibliography database embedded, as in [LaTeX/Bibliography Management: #1 Embedded system](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Embedded_system) ...

Now, I want to use `letter` documentclass, for which the bibliography needs to be defined ([Re: Environment thebibliography undefined when using letter](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3359#p29869))

So what I end up is with this example (code below, compiled with just `pdflatex`, no `bibtex`<sup>(*which I'd like to avoid in this case*)</sup>):

[image: multibib-embedded.png]

... obviously, something works (`multibib` recognized primary and secondary cites, assigning them number "1" as start) -- however I don't get two, separate primary and secondary list of references; would that be possible in this context? (*doesn't have to be with `multibib`, but I'd like to avoid a separate `.bib` file and a `bibtex` call*)

EDIT: I'd also like separate cite keys (i.e. rendered as `[a1]` and `[b1]`; not yet sure if `multibib` can do that; <sup>edit: no it cant, [multibib.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf) says "*You can also edit the .bbl files created by BibTEX and add 'a', 'b',. . . to the labels, but your changes will be overwritten by subsequent BibTEX runs.*" and recommends `\cite[a]{key}`</sup>) - how possible would that be?

The code is this:

```
\documentclass{letter}

% Environment thebibliography undefined when using letter: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3359
\makeatletter
\setlength \labelsep {.5em}
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip
  .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em} \let\@openbib@code\@empty
\newcommand\refname{References}
\newcommand\section{\@startsection
  {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
{\section*{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth \advance\leftmargin\labelsep \@openbib@code
    \usecounter{enumiv}%
    \let\p@enumiv\@empty \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy \clubpenalty4000 \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m} {\def\@noitemerr {\@latex@warning{Empty
      `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{pri}{Primary sources}
\newcites{sec}{Secondary sources}

\begin{document}


\begin{letter}{Addressee}
Blah, blah - content...

Primary cite: \citepri{lamport94} ...

Secondary cite: \citesec{lamport94} ...


\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.

\bibitem{lamport95}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1995.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{letter}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under your `keyword` filter approach with `biblatex`, superficial adjustments to the `labelnumber` field (such as adding the suffix `a` or `b` and resetting the secondary entry count) can be made by redefining the `labelnumber` format. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\newcounter{bbx:primcount}
\setcounter{bbx:primcount}{0}

% Count number of  primary entries; expand labelnumberwidth
% to accommodate suffixes (NB: this might need tweaking when there
% are relatively many more secondary entries)
\makeatletter
\AtDataInput{%
  \ifkeyword{secondary}
    {}
    {\addtocounter{bbx:primcount}{1}%
     \blx@setlabwidth{\labelnumberwidth}{%
       \csuse{abx@ffd@*@labelnumberwidth}{\thefield{labelnumber}a}}}}
\makeatother

% Print labelnumbers with suffixes, adjust secondary labelnumber
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifkeyword{secondary}
    {{\number\numexpr#1-\value{bbx:primcount}}b}
    {#1a}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Filler text \cites[10--15]{aristotle:anima}{aristotle:physics}.
Filler text \cite[23--25]{nussbaum}. Filler text \cite{hyman}.
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Primary Sources (a)}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,title={Secondary Sources (b)}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This solution assumes that all entries are assigned one of the keywords `primary` or `secondary`, but entries without the latter keyword can be treated as primary by replacing the filter `keyword=primary` with `notkeyword=secondary`.

The same problem but with prefixes to the `labelnumber` is relatively easy using the `prefixnumbers` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Filler text \cites[10--15]{aristotle:anima}{aristotle:physics}.
Filler text \cite[23--25]{nussbaum}. Filler text \cite{hyman}.
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Primary Sources},prefixnumbers={A}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,title={Secondary Sources},prefixnumbers={B}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for that, @Audrey; it looks great with `labelnumber` like this :) Cheers!

Comment: Just a few notes to self: first, note both `\ifkeywords` refer to "secondary" (*'primary' is not processed explicity*);  also, if you want to change the label display to, say, [A1] [B1] - then only the *second* `\ifkeyword` needs to be changed, i.e. '`\ifkeyword{secondary} {B{\number\numexpr#1-\value{bbx:primcount}}} {A#1}`'... Cheers!

Comment: Many thanks for those clarifications, @Audrey - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. from [Re: Biblatex package and multiple biliographies](http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg75133.html), I got that "*Biblatex provides native support for multiple bibliographies.*", and in that case `multibib` is not needed, and you can still have an inline file.

So, just with using `biblatex` (using example in [2905#2922](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2905/how-can-i-list-references-from-bibtex-file-in-line-with-commentary/2922#2922)), I managed to get - more or less - what I wanted (all in one file, no bibtex calls, split bibliographies):

[image: biblatex-multi]

... and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{biblatex} % tlmgr install biblatex etoolbox logreq
\usepackage{filecontents} % tlmgr install filecontents
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}

% unicode characters
% note \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx} breaks biblatex
%  with "Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'ucs'"
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx} %

% letter doesn't have \section,\subsection, so:
\def\section*#1{#1}
\def\subsection*#1{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  keywords = {primary},
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
@article{audactor2005pflanzen,
  keywords = {secondary},
  title = {Wie Pflanzen hören... die Geheimnisse der Sonobotanik},
  author = {Prof. Dr. Hortensia Audactor},
  journal = {Draft: \url{http://www.inventionen.de/vortrag_audactor.html}},
  year = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

% \usepackage{multibib} % incompatible


\begin{document}


\begin{letter}{Addressee}
Blah, blah - content...

Primary cite: \cite[\nopp a]{Bli74},

Secondary cite:  \cite[\nopp b]{audactor2005pflanzen}

\ \\

\hrule
\printbibheading
\hrule

\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Primary Sources (a)}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Secondary Sources (b)}]


\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: note the use of keywords to split the bibliographies; [The Biblatex Package pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) notes some other methods too.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: [biblatex: multiple styles - TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34827/biblatex-multiple-styles), or rather [biblatex - two bibliographies with two different styles in same document - TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10104/two-bibliographies-with-two-different-styles-in-same-document)