# Customized citation keys with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have what follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@ARTICLE{refconf,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    keywords = {conference}}
@ARTICLE{refjour,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    keywords = {journal}}
@ARTICLE{ref,
    author = {author},
    title = {title}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\begin{document}
\cite{refjour}, \cite{refconf}, \cite{ref}
\subsection{Personal Conference references}
\printbibliography[keyword=conference,heading=bibempty]
\subsection{Personal Journal references}
\printbibliography[keyword=journal,heading=bibempty]
\subsection{Other references}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty]
\end{document}
```

which is not too bad but I need to customize the labels such that `\cite{refjour}` yields [j.1] (j. for journal) in the main text as well as in the list of references, and that `\cite{refconf}` yields [c.1], and finally `\cite{ref}` yields [1].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29780/4483) to this one was recently posted. Prefixes to `labelnumber` can be easily added using the `prefixnumbers` option of `\printbibliography`. This option needs `defernumbers` enabled globally. For the last reference list, you'll probably want to filter out the previous keywords. The `notkeyword` filter can be used more than once. All this is demonstrated using your MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{refconf,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    keywords = {conference}}
@ARTICLE{refjour,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    keywords = {journal}}
@ARTICLE{ref,
    author = {author},
    title = {title}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{refjour}, \cite{refconf}, \cite{ref}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=conference,prefixnumbers={c.},
  heading=subbibliography,title={Personal Conference references}]
\printbibliography[keyword=journal,prefixnumbers={j.},
  heading=subbibliography,title={Personal Journal references}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=journal,notkeyword=conference,prefixnumbers={},
  heading=subbibliography,title={Other references}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had not seen the similar question. It seems that you do not like the `\subsection{Personal conference references}` together with `\printbibliography[heading=empty]` structure: is there a reason for this?

Comment: @pluton No - I just wanted to demonstrate another way to generate the section titles.

Comment: one problem: if I use `\printbibliography[notkeyword=journal,notkeyword=conference]` before the two other ones, the numbering will be correct, ie I'll get [1], [c.1], and [j.1]. But if I use it afterwards, I'll get [c.1], [j.1], and [2]. It looks like option `defernumbers=true` has no effect in the second case?

Comment: @pluton Sorry - I should have tested your example. Looks like prefixes are all-or-nothing with multiple bibliographies. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: A more correct way may be to use `resetnumbers` instead of `prefixnumbers= {}` in the last one