# How to make a bib entry appear also in the main document

Tags: bibliographies

I have a reference which has a bib entry and appears in the bibliography. I want to be able to include the entire entry, exactly as it appears in the bibliography, somewhere else in the document.

Is there any way to do that other than to manually write it and format it to look similar?

Comment: Are you using bibtex or biblatex? What bibliography style are you using? Please give more information

Comment: I am using bibtex with bibliography style plain.

Comment: Similar to tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/how-to-cite-one-bibentry-in-full-length-in-the-body-text which uses `natbib`.

Comment: The same problem is also discussed here [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135930/use-bibentry-with-biblatex] and here [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126226/how-do-i-instruct-fullcite-to-use-maxbibnames-rather-than-maxcitenames]

Answer (score 21):

Here is an example using `biblatex` as @henrique suggests in his answer. Biblatex provides the `\fullcite` command to achieve what you are seeking.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{auth1:2000,
title = {A book},
author = {A. Thor},
date = {2000},
publisher = {Some Company},
location = {A City}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{auth1:2000}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `\printbibliography` command is not necessary, but it is useful in the example to illustrate that the `\fullcite` command produces text similar to that found in the bibliography.  You will notice that the `\fullcite` command does not provide punctuation at the end of the entry.  Therefore, something like

```
\fullcite{auth1:2000}.
```

is needed to get that punctuation.

Comment: Is it possible to use this with `natbib`?

Comment: @Grzenio: http://stefaanlippens.net/bibentry

Comment: I think this should refer to [this older answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2922/28346), from which the present answer has been adapted.

Comment: I used this solution and got errors like "I found no \citation commands", "I found no \bibdata command", "I found no \bibstyle command".     I replaced "backend=biber" with "backend=bibtex" and it worked!

Answer (score 11):

You can do that with the `bibentry` package.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{bibentry}
      \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
      @misc{ Nobody06,
               author = "Nobody Jr",
               title = "My Article",
               year = "2006" }
      \end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nobibliography*% this command tells bibentry to load the bibliography database from the \bibliography command
\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle
Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Nobody06}.
Blablabla said Nobody in \bibentry{Nobody06}.% here's how you can print the bibliographic entry within text.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

But I recommend you take a look at the `biblatex` package.

Comment: This can be useful to people who only have one source for the whole report

Comment: Just want to add a comment because it took me some time to figure out what was preventing this solution from working for me. `\bibentry` is for some reason not compatible with the use of `usepackage[french]{babel}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130344/using-citep-leads-to-missing-endcsname-inserted-error

Comment: I'm having difficulties making this work. I have a multi-source document and as soon as I use `\nobibliography*` after `\usepackage{bibentry}`, I start getting errors of the type ´./thesis.bbl:51: Undefined control sequence.
\BR@@lbibitem ... \BR@backrefprint \BRorg@bibitem 
                                                  [{#1}]{#2}#3\BR@backref {#2}
l.51 ´. Any idea why?