# How to cite one bibentry in full length in the body text?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am using the `natbib` package.

Now I want to have a bibliography entry cited in full length in the text. That should also appear in the bibliography are. For example

> Text text...
>
> Mr. ABCD (2012) HELLO WORL, This is a cite in Page...
>
> text text...
>
> .....bib area...
>   Mr. bbb sss ..
>   Mr. ABCD (2012) HELLO WORL, This
>   is a cite in Page...

Comment: Similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44394/how-to-make-a-bib-entry-appear-also-in-the-main-document which uses `bibtex`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use the `\bibentry` command from the `bibentry` package:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

A full in-text cite of \bibentry{goossens93}.

A regular citation of \cite{goossens93}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for a nice reply. It **worked fine** when I tested using your example. However, it did not work for me (where I was using ...\documentclass{article}... my bad luck?) OK, thank you very much.

Comment: @Droid-Bird: if you want to, you can add to your question a minimal version of a document illustrating the mentioned problem, so we can try to detect the it; you could also open a fresh follow-up question with a link to this one.

Comment: Thanks much. Finally it worked for me too. I think I had \nobibliography* command missing at the top of the file. By the way what does this command do? Why is it necessary? Do you mind to take a sec to tell me? Thank you.

Comment: @Droid-Bird: sure. Since a regular list of references is used (via the `\bibliography{mytestbib}` command in my example code), the `\nobibliography*` will load the same same `.bbl` ﬁle as `\bibliography`, but avoiding messages about multiple `\bibdata` commands and warnings from about multiply deﬁned citations.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Any idea how to convince hyperref to point to the one at the end (from References) rather than the one in the text?

Comment: Just what I need.  But do you know if I can use `\bibentry` without the reference also showing up in the `\biblography` list.  The application is to use `\bibentry` in an appendix as a separate footnoted citation list for the appendix, but not have the citation show up in the main document's reference list, which occurred prior.

Comment: @Droid-Bird  ```\nobibliography``` allows you to use a reference even without a bibliography section at the end of the document. I don't know why it is necessary even when such a section exists.

Comment: I'm also not seeing anything when I insert the `\bibentry` in my sources. I'm using the [ACM article template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/association-for-computing-machinery-acm-sig-proceedings-template/bmvfhcdnxfty) (you might add a `\bibentry` in file `sample-authordraft.tex` somewhere around line 651). If I insert `\nobibliography*` before the document begins, every citation produces a _runaway argument?_ from the bibliography file. Am I missing anything obvious or is this style just not compatible with `bibentry`?

Comment: For me \bibentry{label} outputs nothing. I'm not the only one it seems:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422161/bibentry-no-output

Comment: I posted my problem as a question with a minimal example that shows that it is not working: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679860/full-in-text-citation-without-biblatex

Answer (score 36):

If you are using BibLateX, you can just use the `\fullcite` command.  for example:

`\fullcite{kumar_exploiting_2010}`

produces

[image]

from the bibtex:

```latex
@inproceedings{kumar_exploiting_2010,
    title = {{EXPLOITING} {N}-{GRAM} {IMPORTANCE} {AND} {ADDITIONAL} {KNOWEDGE} {BASED} {ON} {WIKIPEDIA} {FOR} {IMPROVEMENTS} {IN} {GAAC} {BASED} {DOCUMENT} {CLUSTERING}},
    url = {http://cogprints.org/7148/},
    abstract = {This paper provides a solution to the issue: “How can we use Wikipedia based concepts in document
clustering with lesser human involvement, accompanied by effective improvements in result?” In the
devised system, we propose a method to exploit the importance of N-grams in a document and use
Wikipedia based additional knowledge for GAAC based document clustering. The importance of N-grams
in a document depends on several features including, but not limited to: frequency, position of their
occurrence in a sentence and the position of the sentence in which they occur, in the document. First, we
introduce a new similarity measure, which takes the weighted N-gram importance into account, in the
calculation of similarity measure while performing document clustering. As a result, the chances of topical similarity in clustering are improved. Second, we use Wikipedia as an additional knowledge base both, to remove noisy entries from the extracted N-grams and to reduce the information gap between N-grams that are conceptually-related, which do not have a match owing to differences in writing scheme or strategies. Our experimental results on the publicly available text dataset clearly show that our devised system has a significant improvement in performance over bag-of-words based state-of-the-art systems in this area.},
    urldate = {2019-09-16},
    author = {Kumar, Mr Niraj and Vemula, Mr Venkata Vinay Babu and Srinathan, Dr Kannan and Varma, Dr Vasudeva},
    month = oct,
    year = {2010},
    file = {Kumar et al. - 2010 - EXPLOITING N-GRAM IMPORTANCE AND ADDITIONAL KNOWED.pdf:/Users/m/Zotero/storage/NJ88HWGE/Kumar et al. - 2010 - EXPLOITING N-GRAM IMPORTANCE AND ADDITIONAL KNOWED.pdf:application/pdf;Snapshot:/Users/m/Zotero/storage/H7EJNT4M/7148.html:text/html}
}
```

Comment: How can I get `\fullcite` to also output the citation key in front -- like `\printbibliography`? Depending on your style, this could be `[1]` or `[KVK10]` (using your example).

Comment: @ComFreek Why not just `\cite{mykey}~\fullcite{mykey}`? If you need it a lot, I guess,  you could make a separate command.