# \bibentry generating error with chicago style

Tags: natbib, bibentry

I am trying to use `\bibentry` (with natbib) to have the full reference appear in the text, based on the example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/how-to-cite-one-bibentry-in-full-length-in-the-body-text) (and others). However, this is generating an error `Paragraph ended before \citeauthoryear was complete.<to be read again>\par`.

I don't have any `\citeauthoryear` style citations in my full document. I have tried removing packages and changing memoir to book, thinking it was an incompatibility. I have also tried the suggestion [here](http://miktex.10937.n7.nabble.com/Runaway-argument-when-using-bibentry-natbib-and-acmtrans-bst-td6274.html) to evade the error with `\renewcommand{\citeauthoryear}{}`.

This document generates the error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}  % allows full ref text in body
\nobibliography*           % needed with bibentry

\title{TITLE}
\author{authors}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Want a full reference in the text here: \bibentry{Bunch2003}

and a normal reference \citep{Bunch2003}


\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

This is mytestbib contents:

```
@Article{Bunch2003,
  Title                    = {{S}oft systems methodology and the ecosystem approach: {A} system study of the {C}ooum {R}iver and environs in {C}hennai, {I}ndia},
  Author                   = {Bunch, M. J.},
  Journal                  = {Environmental Management},
  Year                     = {2003},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {182-197},
  Volume                   = {31}
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE** It appears the incompatibility is with the `chicago` bibstyle. The error disappears with `apalike`. Any guidance on how to fix it so I could continue to use `chicago`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm able to replicate the problem you report if I use the `memoir` document class, but not if I use the `article` class. It may be that there's an incompatibility between the `memoir` class and the `bibentry` package; however, I'm not sure at this point.

Comment: I am getting it in the `article` class too.

Comment: Imho chicago is not compatible with bibentry. It inserts `\citeauthoryear` in the optional argument of bibitem and this breaks when bibentry tries to read the bbl. Why don't you use biblatex instead of natbib?

Comment: It seems to work if you add this *before* the `\nobibliography`: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\BR@b@bibitem[2][]{\BR@bibitem[#1]{#2}\BR@c@bibitem{#2}}
\makeatother `.

Comment: That fixed it thanks. If you want to write it as an answer, I can accept it. I should investigate biblatex, but I am really not that confident with LaTeX and natbib usually works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work if you add

```
 \makeatletter 
 \renewcommand\BR@b@bibitem[2][]{\BR@bibitem[#1]{#2}\BR@c@bibitem{#2}}           
 \makeatother
```

*before* `\nobibliography`.