# \fullcite alternative, when required to use bst file?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I need to use a given .bst file, and thus I am restricted to using plain BibTeX.

Is there some method to get something equivalent to BibLaTeX's `\fullcite` in this situation?

Comment: it depends on the bst and the bbl it creates, but I would say that it is rather improbable that it will work.

Comment: You might try with the `bibentry` package (part of `natbib`) or the `usebib` package.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49048/35864 has an example with `bibentry`. With `usebib` you would have to piece the entry together manually (and would run into issues with names lists, which `usebib` does not parse as BibTeX).

Comment: Bibentry doesn't work for me. It doesn't produce any output, but a warning from hyperref about creating a duplicate pdf link label: `pdfTeX warning ext4: destination with the same identifier name{cite.xxxx2015} has been already used, duplicate ignored`. I found a solution that works for me (I'll post it as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

For my setup, the bibentry package (see [How to cite one bibentry in full length in the body text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49048/35864)) did not work. I'd get one of these errors or warnings:

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

pdfTeX warning ext4: destination with the same identifier name{cite.xxxx2015} 
has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

For my purposes however, I was able to exploit that the bibliography entries follow the pattern `\bibitem[LABEL]{CITEKEY} BIBLIOGRAPHYENTRY\par`. Since what I needed was an excerpt from the bibligraphy I defined

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\filterbib}[1]{
  % Requires enumitem package.
  \nocite{#1}% ensure that the entries are in the bibliography.
  \def\bibitem[##1]##2##3\par{
    \edef\fb@keyA{##2}
    \foreach \fb@keyB in {#1}{
      \ifx\fb@keyA\fb@keyB \item ##3\fi
    }
  }
  \begingroup
  \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{
    \itemize
  }{\enditemize}
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}{}{%
    \PackageWarning{kdb:backmatter}{No file \jobname.bbl}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\filterbib{Adles2008prb,Eisenthal2006,Bauer2015}

\bibliographystyle{draftabbrev}
\bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

The solution is rough, but works. Some limitations:

- The citations are always added to the main bibliography.
- The citations always have the same order as in the bibliography (intentional).
- Lack of checking for invalid keys, though the \nocite *should* take care of that.
- Depends on the formatting of the .bbl file: For instance, if there is no empty line between the last citation and the \end{thebibliography}, it will fail.