# How to insert a reference into the text?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Usually we put references at the end of a text.

For my now paper I would like to add bibliographical information into the text so that the reader need not turn to the last section of the document but can read it in the flow of the text:

> So to create a spaceship the obligatory starting point is Dewell's work:
>
> [Dewell] How to create a spaceship, Journal of Astronomy, June 2054
>
> In that work, he emphasizes ...

Is this a usual use case of LaTeX and BibTeX? How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can show the Author's name and year, with a list at the end. Or you can show a symbol or number key, and put the full reference as a footnote or even a margin-note. Would any of these suit your needs?. These are quite standard approaches. If you want the full reference within the text, I have not seen this, as it might break the text flow for the reader, but it seems feasible. The problem might be referencing the same article multiple times, and not putting the whole info every time.

Comment: This is a duplicate of 
 [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/how-to-cite-one-bibentry-in-full-length-in-the-body-text) but I strongly suggest use orthodox cites and references, but with also back references (of course, with both linked  for non-printed PDFs, easy to do with biblatex)  or show  the references as footnotes (also easy with biblatex).

Comment: @Fran thanks, that worked.