# How not to generate References with \bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

This is a follow-up to

[How to cite one bibentry in full length in the body text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/how-to-cite-one-bibentry-in-full-length-in-the-body-text)

The `\bibliography` command does two things: names the bibliography file *and* generates the References section.

Can I achieve somehow that I would only name the bibliography file but wouldn't generate the References section? I want to generate the references in-text as the mentioned question describes.

Comment: You might use the `footbib` package, which makes the references appear as footnotes.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a real bibliography, drop the `\bibliography{<my bibfile>}` and use `\nobibliography{<my bibfile>}` (at the beginning of the document body - or at least before the first `\bibentry`) instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography{xampl}

A full in-text cite of \bibentry{article-full}.
\end{document}
```

[image: A full in-text cite of L[eslie] A. Aamport. The gnats and gnus document preparation system. G-Animal’s Journal, 41(7):73+, July 1986. This is a full ARTICLE entry.]

The example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49051/35864 uses `\nobibliography*` since it actually prints a normal bibliography with `\bibliography{<my bibfile>}`.