# \fullcite with thebibliography

Tags: citing

How do you `\fullcite` with thebibliography?

I am on a `scrletter` and just want the full bibitem in text to be displayed.

```latex
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}

    \fullcite{knuth}

    \begin{thebibliography}{9}

        \bibitem{knuth}
        Donald E. Knuth (1986) Addison-Wesley Professional.

        \bibitem{lamport94}
        Leslie Lamport (1994) Addison
        Wesley, Massachusetts, 2nd ed.

    \end{thebibliography}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try the [`bibentry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibentry) package. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49048/35864.

Comment: tried it, doesn't work with thebibliography
Full Scale bib file would be needed