# Adding the text of a bibentry to the main document in revtex4-2

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, revtex, bibentry

I am trying to get an "in-line" citation (they are usually used in the abstract or in figure captions) in latex using the revtex4-2 documentclass. It should be something like

> This is some text, and here is some reference [b. aa, *Reference Title* (Source, 2023)].

The code is

```
\documentclass[reprint, nofootinbib, amsmath, amssymb, aps]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@book{ref,
  author = {aa, bb},
  title = {Reference Title},
  year = 2023,
  publisher = {dd},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is some text, and here is some reference [\bibentry{ref}]

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}
\bibliography{testbib}

\end{document}
```

Which produces a page with the text

> This is some text, and here is some reference []

followed by a horizontal line (which indicates that the references are following) and

> [1] b. aa, Reference Title (dd, 2023).

which is the usual bibliography.

So there are two problems here. First, the entry is not displayed in the text, and secondly, the reference still appears in the bibliography. How can I add such an inline citation?

Comment: Do you want a normal bibliography, but one which doesn't include any `\bibentry` citations?

Comment: @DaiBowen Yes, exactly. Any normally cited entry (e.g. using `\cite`) should appear in the regular bibliography in the end.

Comment: This isn't possible with `\bibentry`, either there cannot be any bibliography, or any `\bibentry` cited references must appear in the bibliography.

Comment: @DaiBowen Then, is it possible to do this some other way without `\bibentry`?

Comment: [How to cite one bibentry in full length in the body text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49048/106162) doesn't give anything else `natbib`-compatible. I have no ideas without manually editing the `.bbl` file.