# Direct citations inside of footnotes

Tags: footnotes, citing

Consider a document in which footnotes are shown as a bibliography items in the citation list. Furthermore, there are footnotes which contain citations. For example

```
\footnote{See also \cite{citation}.}
```

shows up as

```
Bibliography
[1] See also [2].
[2] citation, Journal Name, *Journal number*.
```

Here comes the question: Is it possible to directly insert the citation in the footnote, i. e. with a command like

```
\footnote{See also \directcite{citation}.}
```

so that it reads

```
Bibliography
[1] See also citation, Journal Name, *Journal number*.
```

without copy-pasting the bibliography text and style manually into the footnote?

**Minimal working example:**

*CITE.TEX*

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, 10pt, notitlepage, aps, pra ]{revtex4-1} 
\RequirePackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\begin{document}
This is a text with a Footnote \footnote{Also see \cite{book}.}.
\bibliography{CITE.bib}
\end{document}
```

*CITE.BIB*

```
@book{book,
author  = "Joe Cool",
title   = "How to make good citations" }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: That is difficult since I am dependent on a given document style... I ll give it a try.

Comment: I am confused, are you referring to Bibliography or Footnotes?

Comment: Can't you just use `biber` as a backend and then use `fullcite` as in this question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44445/16868

Answer (score 1):

I must preface my answer by saying I did a solution in the article class rather than the class you gave (because my antique system couldn't conveniently download the new packages).  Hopefully, these results still apply.

Perhaps you could get what you want with either the optional argument to `\cite` or else the `\nocite` command.

junk.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}

This is a text with a Footnote \footnote{Also see \cite[Joe Cool,
\textit{How to make a good citation}]{bk1}.}.  For the default document
class, the use of the optional argument may not be to your liking.
However, I didn't (couldn't) try it for revtex4.1 class.

Alternately, you might try this\footnote{Also see \nocite{bk2} citation
Sam Cool, \textit{What He Said}.}

In both these cases, BibTeX doesn't put the cite material in the
footnote, you do.  However, since you know the cite material, it won't
be prone to screw-ups if your references get renumbered.
\bibliography{junk}
\end{document}
```

and junk.bib

```
@book{bk1,
author  = "Joe Cool",
title   = "How to make good citations" }

@book{bk2,
author  = "Sam Cool",
title   = "What He Said" }
```

And here is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is to mix numeric citations and something more like Chicago style or APA citations. Maybe one of the citation packages allows that. I usually use natbib, which many different citation commands, including commands which just output parts of a citation--that might allow you to construct the citation you want. I'm not sure whether natbib is flexible enough for what you want, but if not, maybe some other citation package will work.