# Bibentry producing no citation

Tags: bibliographies, bibentry

I can't get the \bibentry command to produce a full citation in the body of the text. The reference in the bibliography at the end works perfectly, but in the body of the text there is no output whatsoever. Here is a minimal example that illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib, bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{document}
   This is supposed to cite in full. Instead I get nothing! \bibentry{Bloggs1950}
\bibliography{fict}
\end{document}
```

The contents of the fict.bib are

```
@article{Bloggs1950,
    author = "{Bloggs}, {Joseph K.}",
    journal = "International Journal of Dubious Assertions",
    pages = "337-629",
    title = "{Misusing Scientific Terminology for Fun and Profit}",
    volume = "202",
    year = "1950"
}
```

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you run `biber` or `bibtex`?

Comment: I'm using bibtex (F11 in texmaker). Should I be using biber instead?

Comment: I get errors with the agsm-style. Beside this you need to add the command `\nobibliography*` (the documentation of bibentry is at the begin of the style). You can't use biber together with natbib, but you should really consider to switch to biblatex + biber instead of using natbib + bibentry.

Comment: see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44394/how-to-make-a-bib-entry-appear-also-in-the-main-document) for examples using `bibtex` with the `bibentry` package or using `biblatex` and the `\fullcite` command
see [the bibentry documentation](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/bibentry2.pdf) as well - you're at least missing a `\nobibliography` command in your example

Comment: Did you get a solution in the meanwhile for this problem? The 'agsm' style does not seem to be a problem. I have searched for hours. I don't get a solution for this. KR

Comment: @DivanBurger- no, I never found out how to fix this problem.

Comment: Same problem with the `agufull04` style :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See comments on switching to `biblatex` and `biber` - if you want to keep using `bibtex`, read on.

You're missing a `\nobibliography*` command - see [the documentation](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/bibentry2.pdf) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44394/how-to-make-a-bib-entry-appear-also-in-the-main-document) for details.

But even with the `\nobibliography*` command there is no output of `\bibentry` - this seems to be a problem with the `agsm` style since switching to `plain` style does fix the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib, bibentry}
%\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Bloggs1950,
        author = "{Bloggs}, {Joseph K.}",
        journal = "International Journal of Dubious Assertions",
        pages = "337-629",
        title = "{Misusing Scientific Terminology for Fun and Profit}",
        volume = "202",
        year = "1950"
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \nobibliography*
    Citation: \cite{Bloggs1950}.
    This is supposed to cite in full. Instead I get nothing! \bibentry{Bloggs1950}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: fixed result]

The problem is indeed with the format of the .bbl file created with the `agsm` style - compare the created .bbl:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Bloggs1950}
{Joseph K.} {Bloggs}.
\newblock {Misusing Scientific Terminology for Fun and Profit}.
\newblock {\em International Journal of Dubious Assertions}, 202:337--629,
  1950.

\end{thebibliography}
```

with the format mentioned in the documentation under '4. Caveats':

```
\bibitem[<label>]{<key>}
Text of the reference entry.
\bibitem
```

they obviously don't fit.

Comment: Thank you was sturggling all around and it was the issue with 'agsm' style

Comment: I am still getting empty output. I have tried including `\nobibliography* \bibliographystyle{plain}` I have tried including  just `\bibliography{bib}`, `\nobibliography*{bib} and `\nobibliography{bib}`. Nothing produces any output.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works (for me):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\nobibliography* % here!
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\bibentry{foo}
\bibliography{main}
\end{document}
```

Apparently, the position of `\nobibliography*` matters. Remove it or place after `\begin{document}` and you get an empty output.