# How to print a full reference with label in the normal text?

Tags: citing, bibentry

I would like to print (full) references in different parts of the normal text. I read that the bibentry package can handle this, but it is not completely what I was looking for. I would like to have a number in front of the reference (as it would appear in the bibliography).

[1] Author's name: Title,....

[2] Author's name: Title,....

In general, it should look as here [How to cite one bibentry in full length in the body text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/how-to-cite-one-bibentry-in-full-length-in%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-the-body-text) , but with the additional numbers.

If there are two or more of such reference lists within the normal text, each of them should start with [1]. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give us some information on your basic setting, i.e. which packages are you using to generate your bibliography?

Comment: I use the same packages as in the MWE in the link. I also copied the method of dealing with the filecontents-environment as it is done in the link.

Comment: I reread the question and have to say, i am not sure what you are trying to do. Can you elaborate on what you want to do? Right now, it sounds a bit like an enumerated list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\bibentry` provides only the citation, as you noted.  However, a `\cite` produces the label you desire.  Placing the two together gets the complete list, as in

`\cite{goossens93} \bibentry{goossens93}`

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@ARTICLE{segl03,
        AUTHOR  = "Segletes, S. B. AND Walters, W. P.",
        TITLE = {Extensions to the Exact Solution of the Long-Rod
                 Penetration/Erosion Equations},
        JOURNAL = "IJIE",
        YEAR    = "2003",
        VOLUME  = "28",
        PAGES   = "363--376"}
\end{filecontents}
\nobibliography*
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document} 
Citing these references in the main text.\cite{goossens93, segl03}, 
I can then access both the number of the cite as well as the full citation:

\cite{goossens93} \bibentry{goossens93}.

Now here is the bibliography.

\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason in some situations: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195254/bibentry-producing-no-citation