# How to repeat a single bibliography item outside of bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm asking this even if it seems to have been asked before, but not in the exact way I would need.

I'm using `biblatex`, and for some reasons (in beamer slides, actually), I need to make single bibliographic entries to appear in the main text, *in addition to be added to the bibliography section*.

In other words, usual citation commands should work as usual, but I'd need a command to typeset the bibliography item (authors, title, etc..), in the same way as it appears in the bibliography section, calling it by citation key.

Example:

```
This theorem has been proved in \cite{MyPaper98}:

\showcite{MyPaper98}
```

which should place the usual citation reference along with the full bibliographic item below (sorry, I didn't draw a mockup), but *possibly* without re-printing the reference key again (for example without another `[1]` on the left).

Is this even possible?

Comment: The `bibentry` package.  See, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215192/how-to-print-a-full-reference-with-label-in-the-normal-text

Comment: Uh oh, that's exactly what I needed. I suppose this is a duplicate!

Comment: Ah no, it's not a duplicate. The `bibentry` package works with `natbib`, while I'm using `biblatex`.

Comment: `\fullcite` should be the command of your choice. See [How to make a bib entry appear also in the main document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44394/35864)

Comment: Yes, just found out it. There was already a question about it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135930/use-bibentry-with-biblatex

Comment: Do we close your question as a duplicate then?

Comment: Yes, with the question I linked above. I cannot vote to close myself because I already voted it before but as a duplicate to the wrong question.