# Double Bibliography entry in table of contents when using bibentry

Tags: bibtex, natbib, bibentry

At one place in the text, I need to add a full bibliographic reference rather than just a citation (whereas in the rest of the document, I need just citations and a bibliography at the end of the document).

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195327/125700) helped me a lot. Using the syntax presented here, I succesfully entered the references in my text while preserving bibliography.
However, having the `\nobibliography*` and then `\bibliography` commands produces two identical "Bibliography" entries in the table of contents. I thought the asterisk used with the `\nobibliography` was supposed to suppress that?

(I am using `natbib` with `bibtex` and no I can't switch to `biber`)

Comment: Are you using the `tocbibind` package? If so, try `\usepackage[notbib]{tocbibind}`

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Well, it removed BOTH the bibliography entries. But I just added the bibliography content line manually and seems to work.

Comment: Well, using `tocbibind` is however (much) easier than manually adding it with `\addcontentsline`, isn't it? `tocbibind` is the cleaner way

Comment: As I said, `tocbibind` with `notbib` removed both those entries. But I would rather have no more or less than one, so I use the `notbib` and `\addcontentsline`. Not a big deal.