# add full bibliography entry in the main text with biblatex when using maxcitenames=1

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to have a full bibliography entry in the main part of the text using `biblatex`. But within the same document, I would like to use `\textcite` with only the first author being shown.

Here is a MWE of the configuration that I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{heitzig2016topology,
        AUTHOR = {Heitzig, J. and Kittel, T. and Donges, J. F. and Molkenthin, N.},
        TITLE = {Topology of sustainable management of dynamical systems with desirable states: from defining planetary boundaries to safe operating spaces in the Earth system},
        JOURNAL = {Earth System Dynamics},
        VOLUME = {7},
        YEAR = {2016},
        NUMBER = {1},
        PAGES = {21--50},
        URL = {https://www.earth-syst-dynam.net/7/21/2016/},
        DOI = {10.5194/esd-7-21-2016}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
style=alphabetic,
backend=biber,
backref=true,
maxbibnames=99,
maxcitenames=1,
mincitenames=1,
giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
    Here, I want just the first author mentioned: \textcite{heitzig2016topology}

    And here I want the full list of all authors mentioned (as in the actual bibliography below) but it doesn't work: \fullcite{heitzig2016topology} 

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44394/how-to-make-a-bib-entry-appear-also-in-the-main-document) is similar, but the solution `\fullcite`, which is given there, does not help here as far as I see. And the `bibentry` package's `\bibentry` command does not give any output (for me).

Comment: `style=alphabetic, citestyle=alphabetic,` is equivalent to the shorter `style=alphabetic` (`style=foo` sets `bibstyle=foo, citestype=foo` automatically). `maxnames=99, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=1,` can be shortened to just `maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=1,` (again `maxnames` sets both `maxbibnames` and `maxcitename` at the same time, since you want to define separate value for them, there is no point in giving them a common value first).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\fullcite` uses many 'cite' settings even though it executes the driver from the bibliography. In particular it uses `maxcitenames`/`mincitenames`, we can make it obey `maxbibnames`/`minbibnames` with

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\defcounter{minnames}{\blx@minbibnames}%
      \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
```