# How to change delimiters of the \fullcite command?

Tags: biblatex

A long time ago I got some help here to adapt my bibliography to my needs.

This works still fine and is very nice. :-)

Right now I have to use also the command `\fullcite{}` and this is sadly not reproducing every entry like it is written in the bibliography.

I already found out to change the number of authors which are written out with the following command:

```
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{3}}}
```

For the rest I could not find solutions:
The persons should be separated by a ";" instead of a "," and the last author should not be added with an "&". Just a ";" like before would be perfect.
Furthermore there should be a dot at the end of the full citation.

It would be really great if you could help me with that :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,DIV=calc, titlepage]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\parindent0pt 


\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,natbib=true, maxbibnames=3,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false, uniquename=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}} %Zitat und Lit in Kapitätlchen

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ % et al instead of "und" with 3 or more authors
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},  }           

\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}[0]{\addspace\&\addspace}  % replace "und" by & 
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} %Sort: Last name, first name
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}  %Sort: Last name, first name

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,report, norm, phdthesis, other, misc]{citetitle}{#1} %Remove quotation marks from title
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,report, norm, phdthesis, other, misc]{title}{#1} %Remove quotation marks from title


%Fullcite change: Write out all authors up to 3
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{3}}}



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Krugmann2015,
    author    = {Krugmann, Paul and Obstfeld, Maurice and Melitz, Mark J.},
    title     = {International economics: theory and policy},
    year      = {2015},
    edition   = {10. edition, global edition},
    publisher = {Pearson},
    location  = {Boston },
    isbn      = {978-1-292-01955-7},
    pubstate  = {Massachusetts},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}


    I am a quote \parencite{Krugmann2015}.\\

    Fullcite:\\
    \fullcite{Krugmann2015}\\\\


    \begingroup
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis} 
    \printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
    \endgroup 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `;` between author names you just need

```
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

To get an `;` instead of `, &` you just need:

```
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
```

Change `last` to `family` and `first` to `given`:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} %Sort: Last name, first name
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}  %Sort: Last name, first name
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

and add the following code to get the closing dot for `\fullcite`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}\adddot} % <===================================
```

Be sure to have

```
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{3}}}
```

**after** the redefinition of `\fullcite`.

With the complete MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Krugmann2015,
    author    = {Krugmann, Paul and Obstfeld, Maurice and Melitz, Mark J.},
    title     = {International economics: theory and policy},
    year      = {2015},
    edition   = {10. edition, global edition},
    publisher = {Pearson},
    location  = {Boston },
    isbn      = {978-1-292-01955-7},
    pubstate  = {Massachusetts},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,DIV=calc, titlepage]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[%
  left=4cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=2cm,
  includeheadfoot
]{geometry} 

\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  natbib=true, 
  maxbibnames=3,
  maxcitenames=2,
  uniquelist=false, 
  uniquename=false, 
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}} %Zitat und Lit in Kapitätlchen

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ % et al instead of "und" with 3 or more authors
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},  }

\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} % <=================
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim} % <=====================

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} %Sort: Last name, first name
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}  %Sort: Last name, first name

\DeclareFieldFormat[%
  article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,
  report, norm, phdthesis, other, misc
]{citetitle}{#1} %Remove quotation marks from title
\DeclareFieldFormat[%
  article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,
  report, norm, phdthesis, other, misc
]{title}{#1} %Remove quotation marks from title

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}\adddot} % <===================================

%Fullcite change: Write out all authors up to 3
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{3}}}


\begin{document}
I am a quote \parencite{Krugmann2015}.\\

Fullcite:\\
\fullcite{Krugmann2015}\\\\

\begingroup
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis} 
\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

you will get the result:

[image]

## EDIT:

Based on the comment of @moewe I changed the code for the fullcite  to:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}% Write out all authors up to 3
      \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}\addperiod} % <===================================
\makeatother
```

Please see that command `\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{3}}}` is not longer needed. Because now `\blx@maxbibnames` (contains the given number `3` in the options for `biblatex`) is used, we need to enclose the code with `\makeatletter` and `makeatother`. The ending dot for the fullcite is now set by `\addperiod`.

With the following MWE (I deleted the `\\` too)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Krugmann2015,
  author    = {Krugmann, Paul and Obstfeld, Maurice and Melitz, Mark J.},
  title     = {International economics: theory and policy},
  year      = {2015},
  edition   = {10. edition, global edition},
  publisher = {Pearson},
  location  = {Boston },
  isbn      = {978-1-292-01955-7},
  pubstate  = {Massachusetts},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,DIV=calc, titlepage]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[%
  left=4cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=2cm,
  includeheadfoot
]{geometry} 

\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  natbib=true, 
  maxbibnames=3,
  maxcitenames=2,
  uniquelist=false, 
  uniquename=false, 
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}} %Zitat und Lit in Kapitätlchen

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ % et al instead of "und" with 3 or more authors
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},  }

\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} % <=================
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim} % <=====================

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} %Sort: Last name, first name
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}  %Sort: Last name, first name

\DeclareFieldFormat[%
  article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,
  report, norm, phdthesis, other, misc
]{citetitle}{#1} %Remove quotation marks from title
\DeclareFieldFormat[%
  article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,
  report, norm, phdthesis, other, misc
]{title}{#1} %Remove quotation marks from title

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}% Write out all authors up to 3
      \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}\addperiod} % <===================================
\makeatother


\begin{document}
I am a quote \parencite{Krugmann2015}.

Fullcite: 
\fullcite{Krugmann2015}

\begingroup
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis} 
\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: I'd use `\addperiod` instead of `\addot`. The former gives a full stop, the latter an abbreviation dot. While it is very unlikely that this will change things, it is semantically nicer to use`\addperiod`. The `\preto\fullcite` bit can be moved directly into the redefinition of `\footcite` similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399252/35864

Comment: Absolutely. BTW: If both `sortname` and `default` have the same format, the `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}` in the definition of `\fullcite` should not be needed any more.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this should work with `biblatex 3.8a + biber`. The sole problem which remains with biblatex 3.8a, when tested with `bibtex8` (the required version of `biber – 2.8, is not available as yet) is one has to add the final dot. So you should only add a re-definition of`\fullcite`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}\adddot}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the dot is there :-) Do you have any suggestions for the delimiters and the "&"?

Comment: It is as you want with latest biblatex (as you can see from the screenshot) – at least it should be since I could not test with the corresponding version of `biber` (not out yet), only with `bibtex8`.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. Up to three authors I would like not have the "et al.". So in this case the fullcite should really look 1:1 like in the bibliography.

Comment: Do you mean that for three authors ase here, you cite the first two, without `et al.`?

Comment: The command \fullcite should produce: Krugmann, Paul; Obstfeld, Maurice; Melitz, Mark J. (2015). International...  So if Krugmann et al. would be written from 4 authors, then it should look like you made it with the et al. :-)

Comment: I was going to say ‘use `maxcitenames=3`, but I see that in this case we don't have anymore semicolons, but commas. I'll try to see for a solution.