# Thesis bibliography and appendix with my publications

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a bib file with all the cites of the document and for this purpose I use:

```
\bibliography{references/bibliography}
```

to import them.

Now, I want to include an appendix with my publications (they are in *references/publications.bib*). The idea is to insert the references without citing them with:

```
\nocite{*}
```

All in all, the final output should be something like this:

```
Main Text
Bibliography for Main Text
Appendix
References without citing them.
```

Is it possible to do it using bibtex and pdflatex?

Comment: One possible solution is to use `\fullcite{ }` as answered here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44394/how-to-make-a-bib-entry-appear-also-in-the-main-document and just itemize your citations.

Comment: @Ilbant it works, it is not for bibtex, though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think you can use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`