# Add comments to bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, comments

In chemistry journals one often notices bibliography entries which contain a comment, *cf.* attachment. 
How to get such results using BibTeX/LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any particular bibliography packages?

Comment: Maybe it won't look exactly the same, but have you ever tried to use the `note` field of bibtex? Depending on your style the note field won't be processed but if your style makes use of it, this could be a useable way.

Comment: @Joseph: right now I am using
`\usepackage[super, numbers, square, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{natmove}
\bibliographystyle{JAmChemSoc}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and its `chem-acs` style. The `begentry` bibmacro is modified to print the meaning of an internal "intronote" macro whose name contains the key of the current bibentry (if such a macro exists). A new user command `\intronote{<entry key>}{<note text>}` is used to define notes. MWE (compile with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=chem-acs]{biblatex}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\intronote}[2]{%
  \csdef{cbx@#1@intronote}{#2}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifcsdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@intronote}{%
    \csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@intronote}\addperiod\space
  }{%
  }%
}

\intronote{Herrmann1999}{Some introductory note.}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Herrmann1999,
  author = {Ackermann, Lutz and Fürstner, Alois and Weskamp, Thomas and Kohl,
    Florian J. and Herrmann, Wolfgang A.},
  title = {{R}uthenium carbene complexes with imidazolin-2-ylidene ligands allow
    the formation of tetrasubstituted cycloalkenes by {RCM}},
  journaltitle = {Tetrahedron Lett.},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {40},
  number = {26},
  pages = {4787-4790},
  doi = {10.1016/S0040-4039(99)00919-3},
  timestamp = {2010.12.03}
}
@ARTICLE{Richards2008,
  author = {Adam, Fatima I. and Hogarth, Graeme and Kabir, Shariff E. and Richards,
    Idris},
  title = {{M}odels of the iron-only hydrogenase: {S}ynthesis and protonation
    of bridge and chelate complexes [{F}e2({CO})4{Ph2P(CH2)nPPh2}(μ-pdt)]
    (n = 2–4) – evidence for a terminal hydride intermediate},
  journaltitle = {C. R. Chimie},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {11},
  number = {8},
  pages = {890-905},
  doi = {10.1016/j.crci.2008.03.003},
  keywords = {di-iron hydrogenases, hydrogenases},
  timestamp = {2009.09.21}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy way to alter this to put the comment at the end of the bibliography entry?

Comment: @Canageek How about using the `addendum` field?

Comment: Wow - this is fine! But could you say me please: How can I make an "extro-note" with this? Meaning a comment at the end of the bibentry. Thx.

Comment: @cis As I wrote above, use the `addendum` field`.

Comment: Oh sorry. Mmhh: I think, for a comment, after all the bibentry-text, I should manipulate the `pageref`-field, because this is the last field, as to my knowledge :() Mmh, I will try...

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this by using the `\cite` command directly: notes added to citations print where the citation is used, not in the bibliography. Instead, you need to create a `misc` (or similar)  database entry to include the required information. Done manually, this requires a separate database for notes (mixing them in a 'standard' `.bib` file is probably a poor idea). However, my [`notes2bib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib) will automate the process, allowing you to write the information inside your `.tex` file. There is then the issue of how to create the journal part of such a note. The most straight-forward way is to work by hand need to do it by hand:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Herrmann1999,
  author = {Ackermann, Lutz and Fürstner, Alois and Weskamp, Thomas and Kohl,
    Florian J. and Herrmann, Wolfgang A.},
  title = {{R}uthenium carbene complexes with imidazolin-2-ylidene ligands allow
    the formation of tetrasubstituted cycloalkenes by {RCM}},
  journaltitle = {Tetrahedron Lett.},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {40},
  number = {26},
  pages = {4787-4790},
  doi = {10.1016/S0040-4039(99)00919-3},
  timestamp = {2010.12.03}
}

@ARTICLE{Richards2008,
  author = {Adam, Fatima I. and Hogarth, Graeme and Kabir, Shariff E. and Richards,
    Idris},
  title = {{M}odels of the iron-only hydrogenase: {S}ynthesis and protonation
    of bridge and chelate complexes [{F}e2({CO})4{Ph2P(CH2)nPPh2}(μ-pdt)]
    (n = 2–4) – evidence for a terminal hydride intermediate},
  journaltitle = {C. R. Chimie},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {11},
  number = {8},
  pages = {890-905},
  doi = {10.1016/j.crci.2008.03.003},
  keywords = {di-iron hydrogenases, hydrogenases},
  timestamp = {2009.09.21}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{notes2bib}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,super]{natbib}
\usepackage{natmove}
\bibliographystyle{JAmChemSoc}
\begin{document}
Some text
  \bibnote{A notes about: Adam, F.~I.; Hogarth, G.; Kabir, S. E.
    \emph{C.~R.~Chemie}, \textbf{2008}, \emph{11}, 890--895}.
More text \cite{Herrmann1999}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

If you want a note about something that will also appear in the bibliography as a separate entry, you might consult [How can I list references from BibTeX file in-line with commentary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2905/how-can-i-list-references-from-bibtex-file-in-line-with-commentary)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any chance to read the bibtex-values? Like: `\showjournaltitle{Richards2008}` => C. R. Chimie, or `\showyear{Richards2008}` => 2008?