# Add arbirary text to list of citations from within the body text of the document using natbib

Tags: citing, footnotes, natbib, endnotes

I want to add a note to my list of citations with text in it, using the same numbering as the other citations.

MNWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Allows UTF8 input. 
\begin{filecontents}{footnote.bib}
    @Article{Brown,
        author ="Brown, Matthew L. and Van Wieren, Ken and Tailor, Hamel N. and Hartling, David and Jean, Anthony and Merbouh, Nabyl",
        title  ="Three-dimensional printing of ellipsoidal structures using Mercury",
        journal  ="CrystEngComm",
        year  ="2018",
        doi  ="10.1039/C7CE01901G",
    }
    @article{Merbouh,
        author = {Van Wieren, Ken and Tailor, Hamel N. and Scalfani, Vincent F. and Merbouh, Nabyl},
        title = {Rapid Access to Multicolor Three-Dimensional Printed Chemistry and Biochemistry Models Using Visualization and Three-Dimensional Printing Software Programs},
        journal = {J.~Chem. Ed.},
        year = {2017},
        doi = {10.1021/acs.jchemed.6b00602},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natmove}  
\begin{document}
    The structure is then exported as a Virtual-Reality Markup Language file (*.wrl or VRML) as outlined previously.\cite{Brown,Merbouh} This file is then imported into magics where the Split Part by Colour command is used. Each of the resulting parts is then saved as a separate StereoLithography  (*.stl or STL) file.\footnote{Stereolithography files were used instead of virtual-reality markup language files due to a bug in this version of Magics that resulted in the structures being shrunk by a factor of 100 every time they were saved as a VRML file.} 
    The structures where was then re-opened in Magics one at a time and the repair functions were used to correct the errors created by Mercury’s export function. 
    \bibliography{footnote}
    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} %chagned from the RSC's .bst file
\end{document}
```

And the output of this (Blank space in the middle of the page edited out): 
[image]

What I would like is the text inside of \footnote to show up in the list of citations as 3, and then the next citation after it to appear as 4 and so on. The intended effect can by seen in [this paper](https://chemrxiv.org/articles/Three-Dimensional_Printing_of_Ellipsoidal_Structures_Using_Mercury/5592715) (made in Word) in entries 7 and 8.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib should do that. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73823/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199061/35864

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the `bib2note` package, as moewe said in the comments.

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{MWE2.bib}
@Article{Brown,
    author ="Brown, Matthew L. and Van Wieren, Ken and Tailor, Hamel N. and Hartling, David and Jean, Anthony and Merbouh, Nabyl",
    title  ="Three-dimensional printing of ellipsoidal structures using Mercury",
    journal  ="CrystEngComm",
    year  ="2018",
    doi  ="10.1039/C7CE01901G",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{notes2bib}

\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib} 

\begin{document}
This is example text\cite{Brown}.
Now this is text that needs a bibnote\bibnote[round]{Structure measured with calipers and rounded to the nearest}.
Now I need to refer to that bibnote again\citenote{round}

\bibliography{MWE2}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\end{document}
```