# Place a bibtex entry mid-document

Tags: bibtex

I am writing a contributions page of my thesis and thus I would like to use the referencing system built into LaTeX to format a few journal entries. Is there anyway to place individual BibTeX entries mid document?

For example I would like to write a paragraph of text, followed by a full reference on its own line, followed by another paragraph of text.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2905/how-can-i-list-references-from-bibtex-file-in-line-with-commentary?