# How can I include one bibtex item in the manuscript body?

Tags: bibtex

Can I include one bibtex item in the manuscript body? For example, I want something like:

> Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
>   blah Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah
>   blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah.
>
> [32] J. Doe, "Hello, World", Journal of Hello, 32(1), 13-24, 2009.
>
> Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah
>   blah Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah
>   blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah.
>
> Bibliography
>
> [1] ...
>
> [2] ...
>
> ........
>
> [32] J. Doe ...
>
> [33] ...
>   ....

Is this possible? How can I do this? I am using bibtex.

Comment: Does [How can I list references from BibTeX file in-line with commentary?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2905/35864) help?

Comment: @moewe Pretty helpful. When a number system is used, can I also display the citation number, e.g., [32]?

Comment: Neither does it by default. It can most certainly be done with `biblatex`; `bibentry` might be able to do so, but I would have to look into it.

Comment: @moewe It was a stupid question. I can just use \cite to display the citation number. Thanks!

Comment: Mhhh, you could of course do that, but it is not as comfortable and clean as a proper solution (I have to admit, though, I'm not really getting anywhere with `bibentry` in that regard). You might like `\newcommand{\fullcite}[1]{\cite{#1}~\bibentry{#1}}` as a barely neater work-around.