# How to create a reading list?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm trying to set up a reading list. For that, I want to have a command like `\showfull(myReference)`, which then actually displays an extended reference that contains Author, year, title, journal some style, instead of referring to it as *(author, year)* and putting it into the bibliography.

So far I'm using   `natbib`, so a solution using that (or at least no additional package) would be preferred.

Comment: What you want is easily done using package `biblatex`, the successor of all previous bibliography related packages out there for twenty years. The command is named `fullcite`. A change to `biblatex` will certainly be a good idea, except you have some complicated style made using `makebst`.

Comment: @Johannes_B fair enough, I've implemented that now. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: If you want, you can post it as a self answer :-) There might even be a similar question on site. I'll look if i can find one.

Comment: Have a look at those two, both even explain the alternative using `natbib`. [What is the most convenient way to create annotated bibliographies, e.g. in a literature review?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33170) and [How can I list references from BibTeX file in-line with commentary?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2922)

Comment: @Johannes_B I have one issue with this solution though: `\fullcite` will give me *all* the information from the bib file, including information as link, abstract. Is there a way that allows me to format the information / choose how much I have, or only selects author, year, title, journal?

Comment: Sure there is, please specify it in the question. Right now, it asks for full cites ;-)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\fullcite` almost got me where I wanted, but when loading bib latex as `\usepackage[bibstyle=reading, doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}`, this would also effect the output of `fullcite` and hence deliver a proper citation without all the additional fluff.

Comment: You never mentioned style `reading`.

Comment: @Johannes_B I just added that after scrolling through the biblatex manual. As I implied earlier, this is my first time with biblatex - I was natbib and chicago-style all until now. Apparently, I can get my old style back with `\usepackage[doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex-chicago}`. Learning while doing :)

Answer (score 2):

A very basic macro that uses `biblatex` and its `citetitle` feature.

[image: foobarExtendedCite]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newcommand{\extendedcite}[1]{\cite{#1}\space\citetitle{#1}}
\begin{document}
\extendedcite{aristotle:physics}

Some nice text
\extendedcite{aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define more citecommands, but a fixed syntax isn't a very good idea. For example, a book does not have a journal title.

Comment: I don't even need something very specific - I just don't want all the additional gibberish in my cite, such as abstract, link etc.

Comment: @FooBar You need to be a bit more specific. Please add a mimimal working example to the question.