# Is it possible to use biblatex to insert a full bibliographic entry in place?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I need to insert complete bibliographic entries in a couple of points in the middle of a text (i.e. not just a reference, but actually the entire formatted entry, as it would appear in the bibliography listing).

Is there anyway to do this while still pulling the reference from an existing `.bib` file and having the text be automatically formatted like the rest of the bibliography?

It is not important whether the inserted citation actually appears in the printed bibliography.

Comment: `\bibentry` of the `bibentry` package can do this, though I have no experience to know if it works with `biblatex`.

Comment: `\fullcite` would be the relevant command in `biblatex`. See also [How to make a bib entry appear also in the main document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44394/35864)

Comment: @moewe care to add this as an answer? I will take it. Or should I close this as a duplicate?

Comment: OK, I decided to close the question as a duplicate. There is also [How can I list references from BibTeX file in-line with commentary?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2905/35864) with the same answers.