# Add a publication in the Latex document

Tags: itemize

I am writing my thesis for and for its separate chapter I would like to present the conducted publications. For example for the first chapter, I am having the following publication:

```
\section{My first chapter}
The following paper is summarized the work done in this section:

\begin{itemize}
\item First Author and second author, name of the paper, conference, 2020.
\end{itemize}
```

However, that latex code simply outputs the paper as a simple item. Is there a special way to place the publication in the text?

**EDIT:**

```
The following paper is summarized the work done in this section:
   - First Author and second author, name of the paper, conference, 2020.
```

Comment: I think what you want to use is **bibtex**. Normally in a thesis, you cite the corresponding publications as you go. You can use it like "```We used \cite{paper1}\cite{paper2} in this section```".  For example as shown here https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex

Comment: I do not want just to cite and add it in the reference section, I would like to present a paper as the introduction of the Chapter. But instead of doing it with the item to find a more elegant way.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you want.  Based on the comment you gave for the attempted answer, it seems like you want this to be formatted as if it were in a bibliography, but to just have that entry here?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://gking.harvard.edu/files/bibentry2.pdf

Comment: Also this: at the end there is a nice example https://texblog.org/2012/04/25/writing-a-cv-in-latex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer based on: https://texblog.org/2012/04/25/writing-a-cv-in-latex

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{bibentry} 

\begin{filecontents}{publication.bib}
@article{lamport1986latex,
  title={LaTEX: User's Guide \& Reference Manual},
  author={Lamport, L.},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
@book{knuth2006art,
  title={The art of computer programming: Generating all trees: history of combinatorial generation},
  author={Knuth, D.E.},
  volume={4},
  year={2006},
  publisher={addison-Wesley}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{publication}

\section{My first chapter}
The following paper is summarized the work done in this section:

\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{knuth2006art}
\item\bibentry{lamport1986latex}
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the most elegant answer so I am accepting this one.

Comment: This worked for me in overleaf where none of the other inline citation solutions would

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{My first chapter}
The following paper is summarized the work done in this section:
\vspace{-3mm}
\begin{itemize}[label=-]
    \item First Author and second author, name of the paper, conference, 2020.
\end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The question is whether I can add the item in a formatted version in a similar manner with the way that they are added in references section normally.

Comment: That was not really obvious from your question. Ok, now that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I faced an identical issue with OP, so I tried the [solution posted by Sango](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525333/202807). This did not work for me. I found a [post with a similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2905). Apparently it works with [`natbib`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2915) but not with `biblatex`, which I use.  The solution for [`biblatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2922), which worked for me is:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \fullcite{knuth2006art}
\item \fullcite{lamport1986latex}
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: output]

If a chapter having one published article, it can be added using the `\quote` environment. To avoid repetition of commands, a `\newcommand` can be added as preamble. My MWE is,

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{thesis}

  \usepackage{times,lipsum}

  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

  \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

   \newcommand{\publn}{

    \begin{quote}

    \singlespacing\small

    \vskip-15mm

    \end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}  %Chapter 1%

\publn{\centerline{The literature survey presented in this chapter has been published in\\} \centerline{Journal, 2020, 3, pp.609-633.}}

 \vspace{10mm}

 \lipsum[2-3]         %dummy text%

 \end{document}
```